# how to make activity running in the background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, bluetooth, gps

i have an activity that implements bluetooth functionality and connect to another BT device and receives data. the main purpose of this activity is just to keep receiving data via BT, and to give me the current value received by the BT via public method `getReceivedValue()` on request.

and i have also another activity that implements the GPS functionality and reads `lat` and `lng` coordinates, and whenever the coordinates changes, i should request, from the BT activity, the current value received by BT using `getReceivedValue()`

my question is, how to make the BT activity keeps running and active and receiving data while i am in the second activity "the one that uses GPS"

Note: both activities belong to the same project in the workspace

Comment: an `"activity running in the background"` is called a `Service`

Comment: @pskink can i write a method such as getReceivedValue() in the service and call it whenever i want? thank you.

Comment: yes if you bind to that service: ask uncle google for "android bound services"

Comment: You need to make service and it should bind then it working in background everytime